# converting bytes program python

Tags: python, byte, converters

I'm just messing around making basic python programs.  Here i'm trying to make a bytes converter.  I think I'm in an infinite loop.  Can someone give me a few examples of why I am?  I am a VERY beginner programmer.  Any input helps!

```
def bytesConverter():
    a = input("1 = KB, 2 = MB, 3 = GB, 4 = TB:")
    if a == 1:
        b = input("amount of KB(s):")
        c = b/1024.0
        d = c/1024.0
        e = d/1024.0
        print(str(b) + str(" KBs"))
        print(str(c) + str(" MBs"))
        print(str(d) + str(" GBs"))
        print(str(e) + str(" TBs"))
    elif a == 2:
        b = input("amount of MB(s):")
        c = b*1024.0
        d = b/1024.0
        e = d/1024.0
        print(str(c) + str(" KBs"))
        print(str(b) + str(" MBs"))
    elif a == 3:
        b = input("amount of GB(s):")
        c = b*1024.0
        d = c*1024.0
        e = b/1024.0
        print(str(d) + str(" KB(s)"))
        print(str(c) + str(" MB(s)"))
        print(str(b) + str(" GB(s)"))
    elif a == 4:
        b = input("amount of TB(s):")
        e = b*1024.0
        c = e*1024.0
        d = c*1024.0
        print(str(d) + str(" KB(s)"))
        print(str(c) + str(" MB(s)"))
        print(str(e) + str(" GB(s)"))
        print(str(b) + str(" TB(s)"))
```

Comment: Infinite loop? You don't use any loop here o.o

Comment: There is no loop at all here, but also no code invoking the function you are defining. Please provide more context, including a problem statement.

Comment: If you are using Python 2, you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: i appreciate your guys input!  I seriously don't think sometimes when I just go off and code.

Comment: A better design would be to use descriptive variable names (like maybe `kb` and `mb`) and refactor to do the calculations outside the conditionals. Maybe bail if the number gets very small or very big, but there is no obvious logic to tell us why you do things one way in one branch, and another way elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not in an infinite loop.  There are no loops and you are not using recursion.

Judging by your syntax for `print`, I believe that you are on Python 3.x.  If so, then you should know that `input` always returns a string object.

This means that this line:

```
a = input("1 = KB, 2 = MB, 3 = GB, 4 = TB:")
```

is assigning `a` to a string.

Moreover, your if-statements are comparing that string with integers, which never works.

To fix the problem, either make the input an integer:

```
a = int(input("1 = KB, 2 = MB, 3 = GB, 4 = TB:"))
```

or compare that string with other strings:

```
if a == '1':
    ...
elif a == '2':
    ...
elif a == '3':
    ...
elif a == '4':
    ...
```

---

Also, you will need to do two other things:

1. Convert the other inputs into integers so you can preform mathematical operations on them.
2. Invoke the function (I assume that you are already doing this, but I'll mention it since you didn't include that line).

---

Finally, there is no reason to call `str` on strings.  Everything like this:

```
str(" KBs")
```

can/should be rewritten to just this:

```
" KBs"
```